# Replacing Text In a Textbox in Continues Forum

Tags: vba, ms-access

It's simple enough to change the textbox value of a form.  But how do I change the text box of a Continues Forum on every record?

The onLoad Event does not work because it just change for the first record only.  Any ideas?

Example Code:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    txb_name.Value = txb_name.Value & "Test"
End Sub
```

In this example, the Continues Form would look like this:

```
 Text1Test
 Text2
 Text3
 Text4
 Text5
 Text6
```

Notice how it only changed the first record.

What I would need is this:

```
 Text1Test
 Text2Test
 Text3Test
 Text4Test
 Text5Test
 Text6Test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution using calling my own function in RecordSource:

```
=myFunction(fieldName)
```

And then, you can just put whatever you want in the function

```
Function myFunction(fieldNameAs String)
    myFunction= fieldName& "Test"
End Function
```

This will loop over all records instead of just the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Why not update the underlying data source via SQL?

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Load()
    DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE myTable SET myField = myField + 'Test'"
End Sub
```

Comment: The reason I need this is because the change is complex and require VBA code.  SQL would not be sufficient.

Comment: Maybe I am still missing something, but the above code works for me.